# Every semi-algebra containing $\Omega$ is an algebra, is this true?

Tags: probability

This is Exercise 2.7.3. in Rosenthal.

> Suppose $F$ is a collection of subsets of $\Omega$, such that $\Omega\in F$.
>
> b) Suppose $F$ is a semialgebra. Prove that $F$ is an algebra.

In the page 9 of Rosenthal, definition of semialgebra:

> A semialgebra of subsets of $\Omega$, meaning that it contains $\varnothing$ and $\Omega$, it is closed under finite intersection, and the complement of any element of $F$ is equal to a finite disjoint union of elements of $F$.

Obsertation: If in the definition of Rosenthal' book, He considers that $\Omega\in F$, the hypothesis is over.

If a semialgebra is not always algebra. I think that this problem is wrong? Some suggestions please.

Comment: Semialgebras are not always algebras, but in this particular instance, the semialgebra is defined to contain the parent set $\Omega$, which restricts it in such a way that in fact it also obeys all the algebra axioms. (This is what you are asked to prove.)

Comment: @PatrickStevens A [semialgebra](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Measure_Theory/Basic_Structures_And_Definitions/Semialgebras,_Algebras_and_%CF%83-algebras) contains $\Omega$ by definition (and is not necessarily an algebra), so the OP is correct in his suspicion.

Comment: I suspect that Rosenthal may use the term semialgebra for a ring of sets. Can you include the definition of semialgebra in Rosenthal's book?

Comment: Daniel, I just included the definition of semialgebra in Rosenthal's book

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the question. Taken from the [errata](http://probability.ca/jeff/ftpdir/errata2.pdf):

p. 23, Exercise 2.7.3, part (b): interchange "semialgebra" and "algebra". (Also for stylistic improvement, swap parts (a) and (b).)

Comment: thanks..............